# aggregate and transform a dataset

Tags: r, plyr

I have a sample dataset like the following:

```
df=data.frame(iter=c(1, 1, 2, 2), exp=c("A", "B", "A", "B"), 
      val=c(2.3, 3.6, 4.0, 5.0))
```

The tabular form will be:

```
  iter exp val
    1   A  2.3
    1   B  3.6
    2   A  4.0
    2   B  5.0
```

I am trying to transform it in a way to group A and B, add a ratio column with value such as `df$val[1]/df$val[2]`, `df$val[3]/df$val[4]`, so the end result looks like:

```
   iter ratio
   1    2.3/3.6
   2    4.0/5.0
```

I feel this should be a job of ddply, but I couldn't see a path to get it done. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df, .(iter), summarise, ratio=paste(val[which(exp=="A")],"/",val[which(exp=="B")],sep=""))
```

Which gave me:

```
  iter   ratio
     1 2.3/3.6
     2     4/5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, list(ratio= val[exp=="A"] / val[exp=="B"]), by=iter]

   iter    ratio
1:    1 0.638889
2:    2 0.800000
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution in base.  It's somewhat more complex than the `plyr` solution, but perhaps it is instructive.

```
do.call(rbind,
   by(df,
      df$iter,
      function(x) {
         with(x, 
            data.frame(
               iter=iter[1],
               ratio=val[which(exp=='A')]/val[which(exp=='B')] ## Or use paste to get a text representation of the ratio
            )
         )
      }
   )
)
## i iter    ratio
## 1    1 0.638889
## 2    2 0.800000
```

It splits the data frame `by` the `iter` column, then takes the ratio of the `A` `val` element over the `B` element.  It assumes that there is only one such value per level.